# Perl regex word matching

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

How do I match the following strings using a perl regexp ?

```
$line="virtual void function";
$line="virtual function";
$line="void function";
$line="function";
$line="pure virtual function";
$line="extern function";
$line="extern void function";
```

i.e match 0 or n number of function qualifiers separated by atleast one space followed by string "function".

It shouldn't match

```
$line="// function";
$line="asdfgh";     
$line="endfunction";
```

Is there something similar to

```
$line=~/^([evp\s]*) function/ ;
```

which can be used for words instead of characters ?

Comment: maybe: `/^(\w+ ){0,2}function$/` or `/^((virtual|void|pure|extern) ){0,2}function$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?:PAT1|PAT2)` is to patterns as `[ab]` is to chars.

```
/^(?:(?:extern|pure|virtual|void)\s+)*function/
```

Comment: Can it be simplified to `/^(?:extern|pure|virtual|void|\s*)*function/` ?

Comment: No, that's not equivalent.

Comment: How about `/^(?:extern|pure|virtual|void|\s+|)+function/` ?

Comment: Worse. Still matches `externpurefunction`, and it no longer matches `function`.

Comment: It matches `function`. But yes it matches `externpurefunction` too.

Comment: oh, right. Two bugs cancel out, allowing `function` to match.

Comment: What do you call `?:` operator and where can I read more about it ?

Comment: Perl regex are documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). `(?:...)` are like parens in Perl. They limit what `|` sees. They also affect what a following `?`, `+`, `*`, or `{m,n}` repeats.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that looks a lot like ikegami's:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = (
    "virtual void function",
    "virtual function",
    "void function",
    "function",
    "pure virtual function",
    "extern function",
    "extern void function",
    "// function",
    "asdfgh",
    "endfunction",
);

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ m{^((virtual|void|pure|extern)\s+)*function}) {
        print "$line is a " . ($1||"'plain function'") . "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "ignored: $line\n";
    }
}
```

Which produces:

```
$ perl 17662838-perl-regex-word-matching.pl
virtual void function is a void
virtual function is a virtual
void function is a void
function is a 'plain function'
pure virtual function is a virtual
extern function is a extern
extern void function is a void
ignored: // function
ignored: asdfgh
ignored: endfunction
```